# Grouped list view looks different in iOS and Droid

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In xamarin forms, the grouped list view appears differently in iOS and Android.

In iOS, the group name is displayed on the top as long as the items under the group is on the screen, even when scrolled. However in android the group name is scrolled up just like a list item.

Is there a way to make this appearance common in Android and iOS?

Comment: This is standard functionality on both Android and iOS. There will be a way to achieve what you want, although it will be tricky and probably very temperamental.

Comment: There is a Sticky Headers lib for Xamarin android done by James Montemagno ( https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/XamDroid.StickyListHeaders ) but don't think it has yet been ported to a custom renderer for Xamarin forms...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Guess there isn't any simple way to do it.